# Issues with converting JSON to CSV with nested values

Tags: json, convert, csv, jq

So far I have had no problems converting standard JSON to CSV with `jq` in the past. But now my data becomes complicated.

Major base tags are `account` and `subaccount`. All other values are variables. The entry `year` got variable values and changed by time very often. That's my task I can't solve.

Here is the output

```json
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "current": [{
            "number": 171883808,
            "commission": 10,
            "year": [
                [1999, 9224, 0],
                [2000, 41919, 9224],
                [2001, 162945, 41919],
                [2002, 397993, 162945],
                [2003, 751570, 397993],
                [2004, 886466, 751570]
            ],
            "status": true,
            "last": 9782473,
            "account": "VFUIJOPQW",
            "subaccount": "BLPORDGS"
        }, {
            "number": 69999012,
            "commission": 15,
            "year": [
                [2012, 97587, 0],
                [2013, 472685, 97587],
                [2014, 605963, 472685],
                [2015, 698634, 605963],
                [2016, 1931094, 1745922]
            ],
            "status": true,
            "last": 9782490,
            "account": "VFUIJOXXX",
            "subaccount": "BLPORXXX"
        }],
    "id": 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean to output a table with `account`, `subaccount` and the `year` array. You could do this with the update-assignment operator (`|=`), e.g.:

```
jq -r '.result | .current | .[]                 |
       .account    as $account                  |
       .subaccount as $subaccount               |
       .year[] |= ([$account, $subaccount] + .) | 
       .year[] | @tsv'
```

Output:

```
VFUIJOPQW  BLPORDGS  1999  9224     0
VFUIJOPQW  BLPORDGS  2000  41919    9224
VFUIJOPQW  BLPORDGS  2001  162945   41919
VFUIJOPQW  BLPORDGS  2002  397993   162945
VFUIJOPQW  BLPORDGS  2003  751570   397993
VFUIJOPQW  BLPORDGS  2004  886466   751570
VFUIJOXXX  BLPORXXX  2012  97587    0
VFUIJOXXX  BLPORXXX  2013  472685   97587
VFUIJOXXX  BLPORXXX  2014  605963   472685
VFUIJOXXX  BLPORXXX  2015  698634   605963
VFUIJOXXX  BLPORXXX  2016  1931094  1745922
```

Comment: that really helped me. How could I do this if I have different accounts. I have edited my post.

Comment: @safect: Updated to a cleaner version that supports multiple element arrays

Comment: it works and many many thanks.